# PowerShell Windows.Forms.ListBox with object in Items List

Tags: powershell, listbox

I like to know which method should I overload to the object get a custom text string display in PowerShell Windows.Forms.ListBox.   I have tried this and other variations but to no avail:

```
$vms_listbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

$vms = Get-VM
#
# Overload ToSTring (I thought this would do)
#
$vms | Add-Member ScriptMethod ToString { $This.Name } -Force
$vms | Foreach {
    [Void]$vms_listbox.Items.Add($_)
}
```

I have tried ith Add-Member ScriptProperty, CodeMethod, CodeProperty, but the listbox still not show the value I intend to show which in this case, the Virtual machine name.

I could have add to the list with the virtual name as:  Items.Add($_.Name), but I prefer to add the instance to the list so I can retrieve it later.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell he listbox which property contains the display-friendly name for the items.

Replace:

```
$vms_listbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
```

with:

```
$vms_listbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$vms_listbox.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

Comment: This sure does exactly what I wanted. Thanks!